# Is it possible to disable the Super+<Number> shortcuts that switch to apps in 12.04?

Tags: unity, 12.04

In 12.04 (and prior, I believe), + (like Windows+1) will switch to the first app in the launchbar. Can I disable this somewhere? I like to use Super+Number to switch between workspaces.

Comment: These shortcuts are hardcoded into Unity in Ubuntu 12.04, so without editing the source code and recompiling, this won't be possible.

Answer (score 4):

You can change the unity keybindings using compizconfig-settings-manager. Go to the Ubuntu Unity Plugin and change the "Key to show the launcher" option.

Bear in mind that changing some options with compizconfig-settings-manager can break unity.

Comment: These shortcuts are hardcoded into Unity in Ubuntu 12.04, so without editing the source code and recompiling, this won't be possible.

Comment: In 14.04, the setting is now called `Key to show the Dash, Launcher, and Help Overlay` So if you disable the Super+<number>, you also disable the shortcut to the Dash. It is a trade-off though

Answer (score 2):

Change keybinding "Key to show the launcher" with compizconfig-settings-manager is bad, dirty and cheap solution. But, changing Super hotkey to Shift+Super is satisfactory for me. Now I use Super+Number to navigate between workspaces and Shift+Super+Number to navigate between application from panel.
Thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't that keyboard shortcut overridden by the Keyboard Shortcuts configuration?

Try going to System Settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts.

Check if there is a key already assigned (Switch to workspace 1, 2, etc.), to do what you wish, and change it.

Comment: These shortcuts are hardcoded into Unity in Ubuntu 12.04, so without editing the source code and recompiling, this won't be possible.